# Capistrano Rails app SQLite3 Cannot open Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, sqlite3-ruby

I've managed to get a Rails app deployed with Capistrano to a server running NGinx & Passenger. On deploy I was getting the "We're sorry, something went wrong" message & was rather confused as the production log was blank. I then switched the `rails_env`  to `development` in my NGinx Conf & now I'm getting:

```
SQLite3::CantOpenException

unable to open database file
Rails.root: /www/testcap/releases/20120407015032
```

I logged into the server, into the `current` folder within `testcap` (which I believe symlinks to the latest release) and ran `rake db:create`, however the db files exist. Having looked within the app's `db` folder I see both `development.db` & `test.db`.

If I run `rails s -e production` and then head to myurl.com:3000 the app works completely fine, which is weird, and it also works fine when I run `rails s -e development` too.

I'm at a complete loss as to what the issue might be here. I'm sure it must be a relatively obvious issue, potentially with capistrano? I'm still new to it so I could well have missed anything but googling so far has been fruitless.

The only thing I can think of is that I've nothing explicitly relating to databases in my `config/deploy.rb` ? However I've not been able to find any guides on the net to help out thus far.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Jack.

Comment: Could be a file permissions issue? To test, try chmod 777'ing the .db files and then seeing if it works?

Comment: Can you run `cap deploy:migrate`?  Permissions sound a likely answer to cannot open errors if the file exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments from Adam P & Ben L above, I managed to make some head way on this. [This Guide](http://strd6.com/2008/09/deploying-sqlite-to-production-w-capistrano/) also solved my issue.

I followed the steps in that guide above and in my `database.yml` file I changed the path to the `production` db from:

```
`db/production.sqlite3`
```

To

```
`/www/testcap/shared/db/production.sqlite3`
```

(eg the absolute path)

I then added this to my `config/deploy.rb`:

```
role :db, "{my vps IP}", :primary => true
```

On my VPS I went into the nginx conf & removed the line `rails_env development` (Passenger then sets it to `production` by default).

And then ran `cap deploy` followed by `cap deploy:migrate`, which worked, and I get the app displayed when I visit the  URL.

I hope this might help someone out in the future stuck on the same issue :)

Jack.